# How to access Feature dictionaries of Datasets in TensorFlow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

With tensorflow-datasets I integrated the MNIST dataset into Tensorflow and now want to visualize single images with Matplotlib. I did it according to this guide: https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/overview

Unfortunately I get an error message during execution. But it works great in the Guide.

According to the guide you have to create a new dataset with only one image using the take() function. Then the features are accessed in the guide. During my attempts I always get an error message.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf

import tensorflow_datasets as tfds



mnist_train, info = tfds.load(name="mnist", split=tfds.Split.TRAIN, with_info=True)
assert isinstance(mnist_train, tf.data.Dataset)

mnist_example = mnist_train.take(50)

#The error is raised in the next line. 
image = mnist_example["image"]
label = mnist_example["label"]

plt.imshow(image.numpy()[:, :, 0].astype(np.float32), cmap=plt.get_cmap("gray"))
print("Label: %d" % label.numpy())
```

This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/mnist/model.py", line 24, in <module>
    image = mnist_example["image"]
TypeError: 'DatasetV1Adapter' object is not subscriptable
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this? After a lot of research I still haven't found the solution.

Comment: `img,label = tuple(mnist_example)[0]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### eager execution

*first* write the code
`tf.enable_eager_execution()`

**why?**

because if you dont you'll need to create graphs and do `session.run()` to get some samples

**eager execution definition ([reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager)):**

> TensorFlow's eager execution is an imperative programming environment that evaluates >operations immediately, without building graphs: operations return concrete values >instead of constructing a computational graph to run later

*then*

### how to access the samples inside Dataset object

all you need is to iterate over DatasetV1Adapter object

several ways to access some samples via conversion to numpy:

**1.**

```
mnist_example = mnist_train.take(50)
for sample in mnist_example:
    image, label = sample["image"].numpy(), sample["label"].numpy()
    plt.imshow(image[:, :, 0].astype(np.uint8), cmap=plt.get_cmap("gray"))
    plt.show()
    print("Label: %d" % label)
```

**2.**

```
mnist_example = tfds.as_numpy(mnist_example, graph=None)
for sample in mnist_example:
    image, label = sample["image"], sample["label"]
    plt.imshow(image[:, :, 0].astype(np.uint8), cmap=plt.get_cmap("gray"))
    plt.show()
    print("Label: %d" % label)
```

**Note1:** if you want all of the 50 samples in a numpy array you can create a empty array such as `np.zeros((28, 28, 50), dtype=np.uint8)` array and assign those images to the elements of it.

**Note2:** for the purpose of imshow, don't convert into `np.float32`, its useless, the images are in uint8 format/range (not normalized by default)

Comment: Thank you very much. I managed to visualize my data in eager mode and in the traditional graph mode. This has greatly improved my understanding of TensorFlow.